# Does Windows 8.1 know it's running on an SSD?

Tags: ssd, windows-8.1

Yesterday I installed Windows 8.1 (clean install - no migration) on a new SSD (Samsung 840 EVO). I then ran `winsat formal` to let Windows optimize itself, as suggested here: [Windows 8.1 SSD Settings](http://www.tweakhound.com/2013/11/02/windows-8-1-ssd-settings-etc/), but I don't see the expected results in the registry:

- From the article: **".. once Windows 8.1 discovers it is installed on a SSD it removes the EnableSuperfetch value entirely"**. *My `EnableSuperfetch` value is still there under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters`*
- From the article: **"ReadyBoot is also disabled by running winsat formal."**. *Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Autologger\ReadyBoot`, my `Start` value is still 1*.

So now I have two questions:

1. Didn't Windows detect that it runs on an SSD?
2. Does it matter for the lifetime/reliability of the SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh man.. All it took was two reboots with some idle time in-between, and all settings were updated correctly. The need for reboots was even clearly described in the linked article.